# iOS 7, UITableView and incorrect separator lines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a problem in iOS 7 with `UITableView` (style: `UITableViewStyleGrouped`) and `separatorInset`. At times, the separator is not visible.

Briefly, using the same table (exactly the same code) if I render the table loading directly all data (for example from a `NSArray`), separator lines are correct (default iOS7 style, correct inset value). If I dynamically add new rows to the same table using something like insertRowsAtIndexPaths, separator lines span the full width of the cell/screen (so, no iOS7 default style).

I tried to force 'separatorInset' using `setSeparatorInset` in both `UITableView` and in every single cell but this did not worked. If I `reloadData` after adding a new row, the separator lines are correctly shown.but this seems not a great solution.

Any ideas why separator is intermittently not visible?

Comment: Can you place some screen shots?

Comment: UITableView loading data from NSArray: [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UC4ev.png) and the same table adding rows using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xA6sp.png)

Comment: Where did you put setSeparatorInset code lines?

Comment: I tried to add it in different methods. Anyway, maybe the problem could be this: when I dynamically add new rows to the table, I append them at the end of the table. By default in iOS7, I see that in the last row of a table the bottom separator line always span the full width of the table itself and every time I add a new row, previous rows are not updated. If I dynamically add new rows at position `totalRows-1`, `separatorLines` are correct (default iOS7 style)! The solution could be to always have a row into the table with `height=0` and then add the new rows at position `totalRows-1`.

Answer (score 12):

Write this code in your `ViewDidLoad` method :

```
[tblView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is problem you are facing ?

Comment: This worked for me, although it's hard to see why there was a problem in the first place since the settings in the nib are correct.

Answer (score 2):

For me the only things working is reload the previous cell, i.e. the one that is on top of the selected cell.

```
if (indexPath.row > 0) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your color in this method and this method into your code. this is iOS7 update.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Comment: Please let us know, is this post helpful for you? did you found any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure clipsToBounds is set to YES for the cell, but NO for the cell's contentView. Also set cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```